# screen shows tv-static / solid color and is very slow

Tags: display

Lenovo Slim 7 14IAP7 - Type 82SX Ubuntu 22.04 (clean installation, also tried 22.10)

Recently, my computer has started flashing to tv-static or solid colors and being unusably slow whenever I do anything involving the graphics on the built in display.

When I use my computer with an external monitor it is fine.

When I use my computer with the "trial version" of ubuntu, i.e. booting from a bootable usb, it is also fine.

But as is, the computer is completely unusable (except through an external monitor). Please help!

ubuntu

---edit:---

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3807
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: it is this one https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/Lenovo/Lenovo_Slim_7_14IAP7/Lenovo_Slim_7_14IAP7_Spec.pdf

Comment: Pease [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @trondhansen yes

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Ubuntu 22.04, and open the terminal and enter this code to enter the grub configuration file.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Add `i915.enable_psr=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

The final line should look like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_psr=0"
```

(You can remove `quiet splash` if you want to, it shows messages that can help with fixing issues.)

Then write out the file using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, and then exit the nano using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot, and the screen should be functioning.

Comment: It is not clear that one has to add  `i915.enable_psr=0` inside the double quote next to `"quiet splash"'`.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me: 
I downgraded my kernel from 5.19 to 5.15

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-5.19.0-32-generic
sudo apt install linux-generic
sudo apt autoremove
```

**Caution** these commands can have drastic effects on your computer.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark next to it and turn it green. This will help others.